# Weird behavior in Python when slicing a string - returns empty string?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, slice

I have a variable `conts` which contains the contents of a binary file (read it with `rb` as mode). Now when I try to get pieces of the string via slicing I would expect to see the proper length for the variables (and obviously the contents, too), but I don't.

Here is code with which I can reproduce this and I am out of ideas what is going on here:

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[10:7]
print "----------------"
print len(conts)
print len(hdr1)
print len(hdr2)
print len(conts)
print "----------------"
print type(hdr1)
print type(hdr2)
print type(conts)
```

The output I get is however:

```
----------------
32174321
6
0
32174321
----------------
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

What's going on here? I thought slicing would create a new string for each slice?

Python version: `2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`

**Note:** the four-byte gap between the slices *is* intentional. The problem is rather that the second slice returns a zero-length string, even though there would be enough data. I found no documentation that pieces (when slicing) need to be adjacent.

**Edit:** after realizing my error: I intended to get from a string longer than 17 bytes the bytes 0 to 6 and the bytes 10 to 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is an empty string is because you didn't mention that you wanted a negative step for the slicing, assuming you did mean to slice backwards.

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[10:7:-1]
```

Will do what you want, notice the `-1` that lets python know that you want to step backwards when slicing instead of forwards.

As an aside, this also leads to an easy way to reverse strings:

```
reverse = string[::-1]
```

The format of slicing is:

`[start_index:end_index:step]`

---

From your edit I can see that this answer may be redundant for your purpose, but it is good information for you to know so I will leave it up.
Here is how you would do what you said in your edit:

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[10:17]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[10:7]
```

But:

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[7:10]
```

I mean should first > second index in a slice except negative step(third param) specified?

So as per your edit:

```
hdr1, hdr2 = conts[0:6], conts[10:17]
```

Comment: Yep, my bad. I actually got confused (too much jumping between programming languages, I guess) `*blush*`

Comment: @0xC0000022L sometimes this happens)))

Answer (score 1):

`conts[10:7]` you probably mean `conts[7:10]`

Comment: Right, second parameter is end *index* not length. -> head on keyboard. Thanks `*blush*`